# Why is my recursive path finding function returning None when a path exists

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding

I am trying to create a recursive path finding function but it always return None whether there is a possible path or not.

The functions for finding the start and end points work.

```py
my_map = """
#####
#..E#
#.###
#S..#
#####
""".splitlines()

def find_start(map, symbol):
    for y, line in enumerate(map):
        for x, char in enumerate(line):
            if char == symbol:
                return x - 1, y

def find_end(map, symbol):
    for y, line in enumerate(map):
        for x, char in enumerate(line):
            if char == symbol:
                return x - 1, y

def neighbours(map, x, y, wall_symbol=None):
    return [e for e in [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)] if e[0] >= 0 and e[1] >= 0 and e[0] < len(map[0]) and e[1] < len(map) and map[e[1]][e[0]] != wall_symbol]

def find_path_recursive(map, start, end, wall_symbol=None, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    for next in neighbours(map, *start, wall_symbol):
        if next not in path:
            newpath = find_path_recursive(map, next, end, wall_symbol, path)
            if newpath:
                return newpath
    return None

print(find_path_recursive(my_map, find_start(my_map, 'S'), find_end(my_map, 'E'), '#'))
```

Actual result:

```
>>> None
```

Expected result:

```
>>> [(1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: When you walk through it step-by-step is there any place in the execution that doesn't seem right? Are you using an IDE? It probably has a debug feature that will allow you to step thru your program and inspect values/conditions.

Comment: Try adding "print" statements, and use a smaller example, e.g., "SE"

Comment: `neighbours()` is returning an empty list, so `find_path_recursive()` returns None pretty much immediately.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, I gotta fix the if statement in the neighbours function, the issue comes from `e[0] >= 0 and e[1] >= 0 and e[0] < len(map[0]) and e[1] < len(map)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from the `neighbours` function which was returning an empty list (thanks to [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) for noticing), the code works perfectly fine (thanks to Python's way with indexes of lists) after removing `e[0] >= 0 and e[1] >= 0 and e[0] < len(map[0]) and e[1] < len(map)`:

```py
my_map = """#####\n#..E#\n#.###\n#S..#\n#####""".splitlines()

def find_start(map, symbol):
    for y, line in enumerate(map):
        for x, char in enumerate(line):
            if char == symbol:
                return x, y

def find_end(map, symbol):
    for y, line in enumerate(map):
        for x, char in enumerate(line):
            if char == symbol:
                return x, y

def neighbours(map, x, y, wall_symbol=None):
    return [e for e in [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)] if map[e[1]][e[0]] != wall_symbol]

def find_path_recursive(map, start, end, wall_symbol=None, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    for next in neighbours(map, *start, wall_symbol):
        if next not in path:
            newpath = find_path_recursive(map, next, end, wall_symbol, path)
            if newpath:
                return newpath
    return None

print(find_path_recursive(my_map, find_start(my_map, 'S'), find_end(my_map, 'E'), '#'))
```

Result:

```
>>> [(1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```